# Pull data from thousands of Sheets files to populate in a new Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, drive

Is it possible to code a script to search through our entire Drive looking for specific parameters? Ex: I'd want to extract Customer Name from C4 and the Address from C5 in each Sheet named "Customer Info" in all Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, by using AppScript for Google Apps.

You can collect all the Spreadsheet file by using the Drive API: [`getFilesByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) will do the job. From that callback you will receive a list (possibly not empty) of files with the same name. In case you want to iterate on a specific file type you can use the method `getFilesByType`.

For each spreadsheet file, you can use the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) Api to navigate inside the document and extract the parameter you want.